# Access STL map by value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a problem accessing a Map by value. I do not want to access the value using `find("string_value")`, but as `find(s)` while `string s="string_value"`. See below:

```
map<string, string> my_map;
string s;
map<string, string>::iterator it_;
for(it_ = my_map.begin(); it_!= my_map.end(); it_++)
{
  s = it_->second;
  if (my_map.find(s) != my_map.end()) cout << my_map.find(s)->second << endl;
}
```

My initial guess is that `find()` accepts const value while `it_->second` is not. So even if my map had the value, the if condition fails. There were no compile time errors though. Any help?

Comment: I don't understand why you iterate trough the map to find the values that you are already pointing too...

Comment: `std::map` models a mapping from the key to the value - it's a one way relationship. You can't use the value to get the corresponding key.

Comment: Your initial guess is wrong, since comparison does not care about constness.

Comment: What is it that happens that you do not expect? As far as I can tell, [this code works fine](http://ideone.com/p4tvsU).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions/comments. I realized that `find(s)` sort of feature doesn`t exist using map. The best bet would be to use boost bimap. However, am not sure if we can have a custom find method that accomplishes what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into Boost, specifically the `bimap` class.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

This will let you make a map where both sides are searchable.

Regular STL maps are only searchable on the key, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `my_map.find(s)`  the map doesn't know that you're looking for a value, and it can't possibly know that, instead it looks for the *key* `s`

So if your map doesn't also contain that value as a key then the lookup will never succeed, and even if it does contain that key it might not be the element you're looking for.

For example if your map contains `{ {"one", "two"}, {"two", "three"} }` then on the first iteration you'll search for `"two"` which returns `{"two", "three"}`, and on the second iteration you'll search for `"three"` which fails.

There's no compile-time error because you're asking the map to find a string, and its key type is string, so it searches for a key equal to that string.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem a few weeks ago. I solved it as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    map<string, string> m;

    m.insert(pair<string,string>("black", "yellow"));
    m.insert(pair<string,string>("green", "blue"));

    auto found = m.end();
    string search = "blue";

    for(map<string, string>::iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++) {
        if(itr->second.find(search) != string::npos) {
             found = itr;
        }
    }
    if(found != m.end()) {
        cout << found->second;
    }
}
```

But this code was written with the C++11 standard so be careful if you are working with an older compiler.

Comment: Of course, it can be done. But is there a point to searching a map for a value? They are meant to associate a particular key with a particular value, it's the association that you should be interested in, not the value.

Comment: The question asks if the key can be an input variable. The above code is not satisfactory because `find("blue")` assumes you already know that the key called "blue" exists.

Comment: why use `m.insert()` instead of the more efficient `m["black"] = "yellow"` or `m.emplace("black", "yellow")`? Why use `auto` for `m.end()` but not for `m.begin()`? Why not use the new range-based `for` loop? Why use `find("blue")` not `iter->second == "blue"`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely
The container map is implemented as a binary tree so it takes always the same time to add a new node. It doesn't matter if you use the method `insert()` or you use the `operator[]`. Both have the same complexity of logarithmic in size n.
The problem of this new range-based `for` loop is that `auto` deduces the following type:
`for(pair<string, string> itr : m) { cout << itr.first; }`
But this doesn't bring you anything because you have just an iterator to each element but you have no access to the address where this `pair` is saved in the tree. 
`*found = itr` isn't possible

Comment: @akella No the code doesn't assume that the key "blue" already exists. You search for this key and if this key doesn't exist your found-iterator still points to the end of the map. So you can check after the search whether the found-iterator still shows to the end of the map or not.

Comment: @tom1991te, wrong and wrong. I wasn't talking about the time to find the insertion point, the map's value_type is `pair<const string, string>` so by inserting `pair<string,string>` you **force** it to make an unnecessary copy, by using `m["black"] = "yellow"` or `m.emplace("black", "yellow")` you avoid that copy.  If you use `for (auto& e : m)` you get a reference to the element (**not** an iterator!) and can take its address or modify it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I debugged the code with both variants and as I have already said there is no difference ... Here the code out of the stl: 
`mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& _Keyval) { // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval); if (_Where == this->end() || this->_Getcomp()(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode()))) _Where = this->insert(_Where, pair<key_type, mapped_type>( _STD move(_Keyval), mapped_type())); return (_Where->second);}`
The code checks if the node is already in the map and add then the new node with `insert()`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes and exactly this is the problem. You work with a reference inside the `for` loop and cannot get an iterator. Therefore I used the ordinary 'for' loop and get so my iterator to the element founding in the map.